# Workaround for DSolve in V 12 when it gives undefined as solution to 1D heat PDE?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

**Bug introduced in 12.0 and fixed in 12.1.1**

---

Reported to WRI **CASE: 4278450**

---

Comparing the following, all done from clean kernel

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The strange thing is that V 12 can solve this same PDE without the assumptions

```
k    = 1/10; A = 60;
pde  = D[u[x, t], t] == k*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
bc   = u[0, t] == A;
ic   = u[x, 0] == 0;
sol  = DSolve[{pde, bc, ic}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But it says in the above answer that it wants `x>0,t>0`, which is why I gave it the assumptions to help it, but then it returns undefined.

Something seems to have gone wrong in V 12 `DSolve` here, or may be in the `Integrate`? I do not know.

Do others see the same result on V 12?.  Answer given by V 11.3 is the correct one.

Any workaround for V 12 to make it give same answer as V 11.3?

### Appendix

fyi, To verify that 11.3 solution is correct, I solved it by hand

Solving
\begin{align}
u_{t} &  =ku_{xx\qquad}t>0,x>0\tag{1}\\
u\left(  0,t\right)   &  =A\nonumber\\
u\left(  x,0\right)   &  =0\nonumber
\end{align}
And $u\left(  x,t\right)  <\infty$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. This means
$u\left(  x,t\right)  $ is bounded. This conditions is always needed to solve
these problems.

Let $U\left(  x,s\right)  $ be the Laplace transform of $u\left(  x,t\right)
$. Defined as
$$
\mathcal{L}
\left(  u,t\right)  =\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}u\left(  x,t\right)  dt
$$
Applying Laplace transform to the original PDE (1) gives
$$
sU\left(  x,s\right)  -u\left(  x,0\right)  =kU_{xx}\left(  x,s\right)
$$
But $u\left(  x,0\right)  =0$, therefore the above becomes
$$
U_{xx}-\frac{s}{k}U=0
$$
The solution to this differential equation is
$$
U\left(  x,s\right)  =c_{1}e^{\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}}x}+c_{2}e^{-\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}
}x}
$$
Since $u\left(  x,t\right)  $ is bounded in the limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$
and $k>0$, therefore it must be that $c_{1}=0$ to keep the solution bounded.
The above simplifies to
$$
U\left(  x,s\right)  =c_{2}e^{-\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}}x}\tag{2}
$$
At $x=0\,,u\left(  0,t\right)  =A$. Therefore $U\left(  0,s\right)  =
\mathcal{L}\left(  u\left(  0,t\right)  \right)  =\mathcal{L}
\left(  A\right)  =\frac{1}{s}A$. Hence at $x=0$ the above gives
$$
\frac{1}{s}A=c_{2}
$$
Therefore (2) becomes
\begin{equation}
U\left(  x,s\right)  =\frac{A}{s}e^{-\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}}x}\tag{3}
\end{equation}
From tables, the inverse Laplace transform of the above is (since $x>0,k>0$)
$$
u\left(  x,t\right)  =A\operatorname{erfc}\left(  \frac{x}{2\sqrt{kt}}\right)
$$
With $A=60,k=\frac{1}{10}$ the above becomes

\begin{align*}
u\left(  x,t\right)    & =60\operatorname{erfc}\left(  \frac{x}{2\sqrt
{\frac{1}{10}t}}\right)  \\
& =60\operatorname{erfc}\left(  \frac{\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}x}{\sqrt{t}}\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, I have the same answer on version 12.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to WRI engineers this is now fixed in **12.1.1**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
k    = 1/10; A = 60;
pde  = D[u[x, t], t] == k*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
bc   = u[0, t] == A;
ic   = u[x, 0] == 0;
sol  = DSolve[{pde, bc, ic}, u[x, t], {x, t}, Assumptions->{x>0,t>0}]
```

[image]

Comment: What, 12.1.1 is released? But the Wolfram Cloud is still "12.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 4, 2020)", strange…

Comment: @xzczd It is available now from your WRI portal. For windows, Linux and Mac.